# Add a custom function in puppet

Tags: ruby, function, file-io, puppet

I'm trying to port a Ruby script in puppet. As far as I know, the only way to achieve that is by creating a custom function in a module. Feel free to tell me if there's another way. I tried my first test as shown on https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_functions.html , I declared a new module in:

```
/etc/puppet/modules/custom_module
```

and edited a new function file called `/etc/puppet/modules/custom_module/lib/puppet/parser/functions/newfunction` with this code:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
    newfunction(:write_line_to_file) do |args|
            filename = args[0]
            str = args[1]
            File.open(filename, 'a') {|fd| fd.puts str }
    end
end
```

Then I used in this manifest `/etc/puppet/environments/desarrollo/manifests/des.pp` with this content:

```
node "develserver" {
        write_line_to_file('/tmp/some_file', "Hello world!")
}
```

And finally when I run a `puppet agent -tod` it shows me the following error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Unknown function write_line_to_file at /etc/puppet/environments/desarrollo/manifests/des.pp:5 on node develserver
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You missed the first part https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_functions.html#where-to-put-your-functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The immediate problem is likely the missing `.rb` extension on your function file name.

Keep in mind that the Ruby code is run *on the master* during catalog compilation. If you want Puppet to take action on the agent side, you cannot use custom functions. You will have to write a [custom Resource Type](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_types.html) (and often a Provider) to do that.

Comment: Thank you Felix, I'll work on that. My purpose is to run the ruby script on the agents so your solution would be the best action to take on them.